# Converting Mesh3D to STL format

Tags: export

I have a code that uses Mesh3D to plot a surface. I want to convert it to STL format. I tried the export function, but it says "Symbol cannot be converted to the STL format". I am pretty new to Mathematica. I am hoping to get some help here. The code has over 2500 lines and I am not sure how to upload it here. Below is the minimal working example of the code. Thank you.

```
Mesh3D[Vertices[{a,b,c},{d,e,f}],Normals[{x,y,z},{p,q,r}],Faces[{1,2,3},{4,5,6}]]
```

Comment: Please post the Minimal Working Example.

Comment: Hii, I have saved the file to Drive. Here's the link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HeIrANxoTFv9Av0-fafWmO9cK2VxBF9U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @VedantKulkarni Please include your code in the question instead. Make it as simple as possible (a minimal working example) and format it as code.

Comment: I have edited the question. I am not sure if the syntax I used is exactly correct, but I tried to make a minimal working example.

Comment: Do you have definitions for `a-f` and `x-z`? If not that sounds like a good reason to get the error that symbols can't be converted to STL"

Comment: yes, they are defined, I used variables just for convenience.

Comment: What is the function `Mesh3D`, `Vertices`, `Normals` , `Faces`?  All of them are not the functions of Mathematica.